# Convert curl to java with file upload

Tags: java, curl

How to convert following curl command to the equivalent java program.

```
$ curl -X POST -F name1=value1 -F name2=value2 -F file=@/path/to/file http://url.com
```

**EDIT:**

I used `hc.apache.org` but I get following error:

> The body of your POST request is not well-formed multipart/form-data

this is my code:

```
    String fileContetn="Content of my file"
    MultipartUtility uploader = new MultipartUtility(url, "UTF-8");
    for (String key : formData.keySet()) {
        uploader.addFormField(key, formData.get(key));
    }
    uploader.addFilePart("file", "file.jpg",fileContent);
    uploader.finish()
```

Comment: Use a library like https://hc.apache.org/

Comment: as a temporary workaround, look into `Runtime.getRuntime()` :P

Comment: @lexicore I use `hc.apache.org` but, it didn't work. please mention my edit. thanks.